# Solar system and $n$ body problem

Tags: newtonian-gravity, solar-system, stability, chaos-theory, three-body-problem

How is possible for the solar system to be stable if has been proved that even the trhee body problem is chaotic with a very small amount of stable solutions?

Do we need to consider the solar system as a very weird and low probabolity solution stable solution of the n body problem?

or if we have a system like that (the mass of one body, the sun, is 99% of the total mass, and Jupiter and Saturn are 90% or more of the resting mass) then the chances to get a solution with stable solution are actually high?

Comment: You don’t know that our solar system is stable into the infinite future.

Comment: we don't know that? but was stable for million of years right? or we don't know that either?

Comment: I’m not sure what we know regarding how long it has been similar to what it is today.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235370/75633 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11661/ , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8827/ , among others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If the solar system is a sensitive chaotic system, can gravitational waves make orbits unpredictable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235370/)

Comment: This is an unanswered question.  I believe the leading expert on this is Scott Tremaine from IAS.  See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97Dg2sWXUiM or https://www.ias.edu/ideas/2011/tremaine-solar-system.

Comment: What do you think a "stable solution" is?